# Layout Design with Pop-up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, android-popupwindow

In Android App, I have a card game designed with the Linear layout and image buttons. On completing a level in this game I have to do the following things as listed below...

1. I have to show a dialog like screen which should pop up on middle of screen. This pop-up should hold some background image and buttons on it. The pop-up should fly from bottom-up.
2. The card game parent screen should be blurred this this pop-up is shown.

I have seen the similar kind of effects in showing ads from Appflood.

Could you please give some suggestion to this effectively.

### Parent Screen

[image]

### With Pop-Up

[image]

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I tried custom dialog but the UI is not as promising as the Layout in a full screen

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple solution (and I tested it - it works pretty well, as illustrated by the pictures I posted).

Imagine you have an invisible (GONE) generic View that covers the whole screen (match_parent, match_parent) and has a reddish semitransparent color.
It would become VISIBLE before showing the Dialog and GONE again after dismissing it.

Since it's GONE, you don't see it and it doesn't waste any space until it becomes VISIBLE.

This approach requires the outer container being a FrameLayout or a RelativeLayout (by setting the View properly: anchoring it to the four Parent's corners).
I used a RelativeLayout - because I really love these containers.

**dlg_red_bg.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:padding="8dp"
    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTopLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTopRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnTopLeft"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 2"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBottomLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnTopLeft"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBottomRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btnTopRight"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnBottomLeft"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:text="Btn 4"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ball"
            android:onClick="clickHandler"
            android:text="Dialog"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/vwRedOver"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#8f00"
        android:visibility="gone"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**code used to highlight the background**

```
public void clickHandler(final View v)
{
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btnDialog:
        {
            vwRedOver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            bld.setMessage("Some Message")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton
            (
                "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public final void onClick
                    (final DialogInterface dlg, final int id)
                    {
                        vwRedOver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        dlg.cancel();
                    }
                }
            )
            .setNegativeButton
            (
                "Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public final void onClick
                    (final DialogInterface dlg, final int id)
                    {
                        vwRedOver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        dlg.cancel();
                    }
                }
            );
            bld.create().show();
        }
    }
}
```

**result**

Before Clicking on "Dialog"

[image]

After Clicking on "Dialog"
NOTE 1: It's dark because of the black background
NOTE 2: You see a black border, because I set a padding on the outer RelativeLayout - you can remove it

[image]

After Clicking on either "OK" or "Cancel" - returns to the initial state (my Dialog doesn't do anything interesting on OK - It's only for demo purposes)

[image]

Comment: But I have used Linear Layout, I hope I have to do this using Fragment Layout.

Comment: Who stops you converting to a RelativeLayout, instead?

Comment: There is lot of change needed to convert it.. instead pragmatically I am going to create a fragment layout and attach layouts..

Comment: I see: "programmatically". As you like... I wouldn't do that much effort programmatically. But who am I to tell you? Anyway, you can enclose all of your layouts inside a Relative or FrameLayout and then use the View method I illustrated above.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

Don't use AlertDialog, you can use one normal layout and one normal class. ¿How?

It's easy, you have one class called "FirstActivity.java", and one second class called "SecondActivity.java".

**FirstActivity**

Designed this class as you like

**SecondActivity**

You are going to create your own popup with ImageView,Buttons and textviews and you are going to Overlay your layout background.

**Popup_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/popup_background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:onClick="go"
        android:src="@drawable/ok" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:text:"level completed"


</RelativeLayout>
```

**manifest**

Declare SecondActivity with custom Theme.

```
......

 <activity
            android:name="com.example.comandero.SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Overlay" />  
.......
```

**Styles.xml**

Add new style for background on your layout.

```
<style name="Theme.Overlay" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Try it and say me please. If you dont understand something say me.